# How can I check file extension of a file in IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, file-extension

I need to populate 2 lists in my application.
The first list should contain only .txt files while the second one should contain .jpg files.

Now what I do is something like:

```
    foreach (string file in fileList)
                    {

                        if (file != "__ApplicationSettings")
                        {
                           ...
                        }
                     }
```

But how can I also check file extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(file) != ".jpg")
{
    ...
}
```